# What do I need in order to draw conclusions from this data?

Tags: variance

I have three techniques, called A, B and C. Each can be used independently when trying to perform four related tasks (Tasks 1, 2, 3 and 4). I have run lots of tests, trying all combinations of each technique being on or off. My results look something like this. Each number represents how many times the task was completed successfully when attempted, using the given combination of techniques, 100000 times. So, the higher the number, the better.

$$
\begin{array}{l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\mbox{Technique $A$} & - & - & - & - & X & X & X & X \\
\mbox{Technique $B$} & - & - & X & X & - & - & X & X \\
\mbox{Technique $C$} & - & X & - & X & - & X & - & X \\ \hline
\mbox{Task $1$} & 433 & 277 & 911 & 492 & 686 & 4211 & 3775 & {\bf 9732}\\
\mbox{Task $2$} & 149 & 1063 & 5562 & {\bf 6035} & 3 & 58 & 1391 & 1708\\
\mbox{Task $3$} & 220 & 1278 & 7014 & {\bf 7018} & 10 & 97 & 2083 & 4452\\
\mbox{Task $4$} & 218 & 1255 & 6142 & {\bf 8656} & 1 & 73 & 1087 & 2056\\
\end{array}
$$

I've highlighted the largest number in each row. Looking at the numbers, it seems that $B+C$ is good for Tasks 2, 3 and 4, and that adding $A$ as well is best for Task 1. But I want to say a bit more. I'd like to be quantitative if I can. My question is: can I deduce *anything* quantitative from this data? Or do I really need some measure of the variance of the observations? That is, I suspect the numbers might be different if I ran all the tests again.

---

**Edit.** I originally presented my question pretending there were 3 techniques, just in order to save space. There are in fact 4. I'm mentioning this now because it might affect how the results are analysed. In particular: note now that the `intercept' is zero, i.e. there is no success at all when none of the techniques are used.

$$
\begin{array}{l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\mbox{Technique $Z$} & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\
\mbox{Technique $A$} & - & - & - & - & X & X & X & X & - & - & - & - & X & X & X & X \\
\mbox{Technique $B$} & - & - & X & X & - & - & X & X & - & - & X & X & - & - & X & X \\
\mbox{Technique $C$} & - & X & - & X & - & X & - & X & - & X & - & X & - & X & - & X \\ \hline
\mbox{Task $1$} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2700 & 1 & 10113 & 433 & 277 & 911 & 492 & 686 & 4211 & 3775 & {\bf 9732}\\
\mbox{Task $2$} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 149 & 1063 & 5562 & {\bf 6035} & 3 & 58 & 1391 & 1708\\
\mbox{Task $3$} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 664 & 0 & 3043 & 220 & 1278 & 7014 & {\bf 7018} & 10 & 97 & 2083 & 4452\\
\mbox{Task $4$} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 218 & 1255 & 6142 & {\bf 8656} & 1 & 73 & 1087 & 2056\\
\end{array}
$$

Here are those numbers in by-column form (for pasting into `R`):

```
0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,
2700, 0,    664,  0,
1,    0,    0,    0,
10113,0,    3043, 0,
433,  149,  220,  218,
277,  1063, 1278, 1255,
911,  5562, 7014, 6142,
492,  6034, 7018, 8656,
686,  3,    10,   1,
4211, 48,   97,   73,
3775, 1391, 2083, 1087,
9732, 1708, 4452, 2056
```

Comment: What are the numbers in the cells of the table? Are they from one person? Average of many people? Or what?

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks for your question. I've edited my question to include the answer. The tasks are performed by computer, not by people. Each number represents the number of successfully-completed tasks out of 100000 attempts.

Answer (score 5):

You can use logistic regression. The dependent variable would be "success" and the independent variables will be technique and task. Task could be coded as three 2-level dummy codes plus interactions. Or, you could code it as one categorical variable with 8 levels. These are equivalent. The former is easier to code but the latter *may* be easier to understand.

Answer (score 5):

It is a good question, reflecting the understanding that data are only an uncertain reflection of reality.  Any solution should therefore attempt to quantify this uncertainty.

The numbers would indeed be different if the tests were run with different inputs.  Assuming these runs are considered representative of future runs and they were independent of each other, we can assess how much random variation there will likely be and use that to inform our estimates of how much each technique influences the result.

Because the proportions of successes were so small, they can be modeled with a Poisson Generalized Linear Model.  (Alternatively, use a Binomial GLM.  In this case it will give almost identical results.)  This model can be used to estimate the contributions of each technique to the successes in each task.  To evaluate the variability of these estimates, *bootstrap the data*: repeatedly sample with replacement from these 3.2 million results and re-estimate the coefficients.  Use the variability of the repeated estimates to assess the uncertainty in the model coefficients.  This can be done separately for each task.

Creating a new sample of 3.2 million values is much simpler than it sounds, because each of the counts is modeled as a binomial outcome.  Thus only 8 random numbers have to be regenerated for each bootstrap trial of each task.

Here is an example of (some of) the information that can be produced with this approach.  It is based on 99 bootstrap trials.

```
======================
        Task 4
======================
            Actual    Mean     SD       Z     p     Min    Max
(Intercept)  5.384   5.383  0.069  78.568 0.000   5.198  5.557
A           -5.384 -13.013 10.915  -1.192 0.233 -27.859 -3.766
B            3.338   3.340  0.070  47.952 0.000   3.181  3.526
C            1.750   1.754  0.075  23.441 0.000   1.568  1.964
A:B          3.653  11.282 10.917   1.033 0.301   2.039 26.085
A:C          2.540  10.153 10.895   0.932 0.351   0.767 25.137
B:C         -1.407  -1.410  0.076 -18.649 0.000  -1.632 -1.228
A:B:C       -2.246  -9.862 10.897  -0.905 0.365 -24.880 -0.485
```

This is a "saturated" model in which the results are teased apart into eight contributions, each of which is to be added and then exponentiated to predict the
number of successes per $10^5$ runs.  The `Actual` column presents the estimates based on the original data.  The other columns summarize the repeated estimates, as explained below and in the code.

- The "intercept" is a base level reflecting overall success rates for all techniques.
- "A", "B", and "C" are contributions attributed to those techniques (assuming "X" means the technique is used and "-" means it is not in the table in the question).
- "A:B", "A:C", and "B:C" are contributions from combinations of pairs of techniques ("interactions").
- "A:B:C" is a contribution from the simultaneous use of all three techniques (a "three-way interaction".

For instance, when both $A$ and $C$ are used for Task 4, the predicted rate of success is computed as

$$\exp(5.384 - 5.384 + 1.750 + 2.540)/10^5 = 73/10^5,$$

exactly as in the data.  However, each of these coefficient estimates is uncertain: the initial $5.384$ has a standard deviation of only $0.069$, but the $-5.384$ associated with $A$ has an SD of $10.915$, making it uncertain whether it even differs from $0$ (the p-value for this test is only $0.233$, which nobody would consider significant).  Indeed, it is doubtful whether technique $A$ contributes anything to the success of Task 4, because all the p-values associated with it ($A$, $A:B$, $A:C$, and $A:B:C$) are high.  Moreover, the large discrepancies between the estimates based on the actual data and the mean of the bootstrapped estimates for the "$A$" columns suggest the actual estimates might be biased--this deserves further investigation, perhaps with a more careful examination of the results of a larger number of bootstrap trials.

(Without the bootstrapping, all we could have obtained is the first column of this output: the estimates based on the actual data.  Because the model is saturated, it perfectly fits the data, leaving no degrees of freedom to assess uncertainty.)

The `R` code that produced this result produced similar information for the other three tasks.  It should be self-explanatory.

```r
technique <- expand.grid(Task=1:4, C=0:1, B=0:1, A=0:1)
technique$Success <- c(433, 149, 220, 218,
                           277, 1063, 1278, 1255,
                           911, 5562, 7014, 6142,
                           492, 6034, 7018, 8656,
                           686, 3, 10, 1,
                           4211, 48, 97, 73,
                           3775, 1391, 2083, 1087,
                           9732, 1708, 4452, 2056)
    n.trials <- 1e5
    n.iter <- 99 # Set the number of bootstrap iterations
    set.seed(17) # Create a reproducible starting point
    for (task in 1:4) {
      #
      # Extract the data for this task.
      #
      d <- e <- subset(technique, subset=(Task==task))
      coefficients <- matrix(NA, n.iter, 8)
      for (i in 1:n.iter) {
        #
        # Fit these data.
        #
        fit <- glm(Success ~ A+B+C + A:B + A:C + B:C + A:B:C, 
                   family=poisson(link="log"), data=d)
        coefficients[i, ] <- coef(fit)
        #
        # Create a new bootstrap sample.
        #
        d$Success <- rbinom(dim(d)[1], n.trials, e$Success/n.trials)
  }
  #
  # Summarize the results.
  #
  dimnames(coefficients) <- list(Iteration=1:n.iter, Coefficient=names(coef(fit)))
  results <- apply(coefficients, 2, 
                   function(b) {
                     m <- mean(b)          # Mean estimate
                     s <- sd(b)            # Standard deviation of the estimates
                     z <- m/s              # A Z statistic
                     p=2*(1-pnorm(abs(z))) # The p-value
                     c(Mean=m, SD=s, Z=z, p=p, Min=min(b), Max=max(b))
                     })
  results <- rbind(Actual=coefficients[1, ], results) # Best (original) estimates
  cat("=======================\n")
  cat(paste("        Task", task))
  cat("\n======================\n")
  print(t(round(results, 3)))
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this incredibly comprehensive answer. I'm in the process of working through it now, so I may come back to you with requests for clarifications shortly. But in the meantime, *thank you*! By the way, your R code has a small bug: replace `n.tries` with `n.trials`.

Comment: I've edited my question to mention the fact that I had lied a bit: in fact there is a fourth technique, which in my original question was always switched on. That accounts for the non-zero intercept.

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo--it was a vestige of an earlier name for the same variable, and so the code worked on my system. (Which is a relief, because it means the output was unaffected.)  The non-zero intercept reflects the overall average success rate: it has nothing to do with the presence or absence of other techniques.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an *answer*, but a report on 'what I did in the end'. I would very much appreciate it if those who kindly provided the answers above would glance over the following text and see if it's "ok".

User whuber suggested considering each combination of techniques in turn, but in what follows, I've opted just to consider each technique individually. It feels much simpler to me, and simplicity is what I'm aiming for, but I would be interested to know if it's still statistically sound.

### Here is what I wrote...

> To give a rough idea of the relative effectiveness of each
>   technique, we perform a logistic regression analysis. The four
>   techniques provide four binomial input variables, while the output
>   variable is the success rate for each task. Since the success rates
>   are quite low, a Poisson model is appropriate. In the following table,
>   we gather the coefficients of this model. The standard deviations are
>   around a couple of percent, so we give the figures to one decimal
>   place.
>
> $$
>  \begin{array}{lrrrr}
>  & \mbox{Task $1$} & \mbox{Task $2$}  & \mbox{Task $3$} & \mbox{Task $4$} \\
> (intercept) & 3.6 & -17.1 &  4.3 & -17.1 \\ 
> \mbox{Technique $Z$} & 0.5 &  23.2 &  1.8 &  23.3 \\ 
> \mbox{Technique $A$} & 2.7 &  -1.4 & -0.4 &  -1.6 \\ 
> \mbox{Technique $B$} & 1.1 &   2.5 &  2.3 &   2.5 \\ 
> \mbox{Technique $C$} & 1.6 &   0.2 &  0.6 &   0.5 \\ \end{array}
>  $$
>
> The smaller the coefficient, the less the technique contributes to the
>   success rate; indeed, when the coefficient is negative, the technique
>   is actually a hindrance. The `intercept' coefficients represent the
>   success rate averaged across all techniques.
>
> In summary, we find that Technique $Z$ has by far the highest impact,
>   and that Technique $A$ tend to decrease the success rate except when
>   performing Task $1$. Techniques $B$ and $C$ are consistently helpful.

### This is the `R` script I ran in order to justify the text above

It's just a slightly modified version of whuber's script.

```
technique <- expand.grid(Task=1:4, D=0:1, C=0:1, B=0:1, A=0:1)
technique$Success <- c(
    0,    0,    0,    0,
    0,    0,    0,    0,
    0,    0,    0,    0,
    0,    0,    0,    0,
    0,    0,    0,    0,
    2700, 0,    664,  0,
    1,    0,    0,    0,
    10113,0,    3043, 0,
    433,  149,  220,  218,
    277,  1063, 1278, 1255,
    911,  5562, 7014, 6142,
    492,  6034, 7018, 8656,
    686,  3,    10,   1,
    4211, 48,   97,   73,
    3775, 1391, 2083, 1087,
    9732, 1708, 4452, 2056
    )
        n.trials <- 1e5
        n.iter <- 99 # Set the number of bootstrap iterations
        set.seed(17) # Create a reproducible starting point
        for (task in 1:4) {
          #
          # Extract the data for this task.
          #
          d <- e <- subset(technique, subset=(Task==task))
          coefficients <- matrix(NA, n.iter, 5)
          for (i in 1:n.iter) {
            #
            # Fit these data.
            #
            fit <- glm(Success ~ A+B+C+D, family=poisson(link="log"), data=d)
            coefficients[i, ] <- coef(fit)
            #
            # Create a new bootstrap sample.
            #
            d$Success <- rbinom(dim(d)[1], n.trials, e$Success/n.trials)
  }
  #
  # Summarize the results.
  #
  dimnames(coefficients) <- list(Iteration=1:n.iter, Coefficient=names(coef(fit)))
  results <- apply(coefficients, 2, 
                   function(b) {
                     m <- mean(b)          # Mean estimate
                     s <- sd(b)            # Standard deviation of the estimates
                     z <- m/s              # A Z statistic
                     p=2*(1-pnorm(abs(z))) # The p-value
                     c(Mean=m, SD=s, Z=z, p=p, Min=min(b), Max=max(b))
                     })
  results <- rbind(Actual=coefficients[1, ], results) # Best (original) estimates
  cat("========================\n")
  cat(paste("        Task", task))
  cat("\n======================\n")
  print(t(round(results, 1)))
}
```

### And this is the data that running that script produces:

```
========================
        Task 1
======================
            Actual  Mean    SD       Z p   Min   Max
(Intercept)  3.563 3.565 0.032 111.734 0 3.480 3.641
A            0.471 0.470 0.009  50.772 0 0.449 0.493
B            2.693 2.692 0.025 106.485 0 2.633 2.761
C            1.103 1.102 0.012  89.164 0 1.062 1.133
D            1.556 1.556 0.015 107.043 0 1.512 1.598
========================
        Task 2
======================
             Actual    Mean    SD        Z p     Min     Max
(Intercept) -17.104 -17.105 0.022 -760.229 0 -17.174 -17.048
A            23.216  23.220 0.017 1402.716 0  23.187  23.268
B            -1.403  -1.400 0.021  -68.192 0  -1.454  -1.329
C             2.454   2.451 0.028   86.965 0   2.383   2.519
D             0.220   0.221 0.014   15.949 0   0.189   0.260
========================
        Task 3
======================
            Actual   Mean    SD       Z p    Min    Max
(Intercept)  4.253  4.255 0.023 181.558 0  4.198  4.308
A            1.789  1.786 0.018  98.931 0  1.742  1.832
B           -0.406 -0.404 0.013 -31.285 0 -0.444 -0.369
C            2.342  2.341 0.020 116.633 0  2.292  2.395
D            0.574  0.573 0.011  49.948 0  0.538  0.595
========================
        Task 4
======================
             Actual    Mean    SD        Z p     Min     Max
(Intercept) -17.066 -17.068 0.019 -906.664 0 -17.120 -17.020
A            23.268  23.269 0.014 1673.551 0  23.241  23.307
B            -1.621  -1.619 0.019  -84.484 0  -1.672  -1.571
C             2.451   2.452 0.024  102.533 0   2.403   2.504
D             0.480   0.479 0.015   32.899 0   0.447   0.515
```

Comment: In my answer I recommended models that include the interactions because they are *hugely* better than the simplified models here.  You can test this by comparing their AICs or by examining the p-values of the interaction coefficients. It is possible to remove some of those interaction variables for various tasks, but if you want a reasonably accurate and predictive model then you must include some of the interactions.  The predictive abilities of these models can be checked with cross-validation or by testing against a held-out portion of the dataset.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your comment. I can well imagine that models that include interactions can be a lot more faithful. That said, what I'm after is something really simple. Thing is, this analysis is really not central to my article, it's really just a remark. So would you say that even if my model is not very accurate, my text does at least describe a sound application of the principles?

Comment: I don't know what to say. Comparing the estimated coefficients of $A$ through $D$ for the models with and without interactions indicates the two approaches lead to two quite different conclusions. They cannot both be correct. If you value simplicity over predictability or insight, then you might still favor the simpler model--but it is not clear that your readers would share that opinion. To me, and perhaps to them, it is very interesting that the interactions are not only significant but *strong* in the sense of having an important bearing on understanding the relationships in the data.